# Lookup Field in List has no selection menu

Tags: 2013, list, lookup-column

I have created a list via Visual Studio and added a Lookup Field to an another list and which is looking for the ID of the other list. In fact this lookup field is the second one in this list. There is a lookup field to the same other list and is functional and usable.

But the lookup field which I have recently added seems to be not existant like you can see here:

[image]

In this Image you can see that for IDfromExternalList there is a selection menu. But not for TaskReferenceID which is pointing at the same List and the same Column (this is only for testing purposes right now).

Is there anyone who has an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you added this column in the list in schema file using Visual studio? If yes, then please provide that XML code chunck, for better understandment.

Comment: Hi @DikeshGandhi, no I have added it via the list view in visual studio

Comment: Ok. Can you please double check the name of the list and title that you have passed in this lookup field? As it seems some issues with that field.

Comment: @DikeshGandhi I have copied the List and FieldName from the Lookup Field `IDfromExternalList` thats why it is so weird that it doesn't work now...